# How to preconfigure wifi on Mac OS X (Yosemite)?

Tags: macos, wifi, airport, keychain

Does anyone knows a way to preconfigure a WPA2 WiFi network on Mac OS X (Yosemite)?

I'm preparing an iMac for a friend and would like to setup his home WiFi while currently far away from the network.

I know all the WiFi parameters (SSID, security, key) but can't manage to validate the manual setup through the AirPort wizard.
I also tried to manually add the entry in Keychains, but can't manage to add the confirmation exceptions on "airportd" and "AirPort" binaries in the ACL part.

Thus, I can't setup transparently and remotely the WiFi connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to the network preferences panel in System Preference
- Select airport, then 'Advanced...'
- Press the plus button

It will work even when the network isn't near.

Comment: Fast, clear, precise. Thank you for your helpful answer !