# How can I add a WiFi network ahead of time?

Tags: ios, wifi

I have an SSID and WPA2 credentials. How can I tell them to iOS?

I've tried:

1. In Settings → Wi-Fi → Other, enter the SSID and WPA2 credentials.

Expected:

- some kind of **Save** button

Actual:

- I only see **Join**, which of course fails because the AP is 200 km away.

---

This is the same question as [#175614](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/175614/6408) but for iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only "pre-define" WiFi access using Apple Configurator.
Create a profile, configure the WiFi payload with SSID/password and "Auto Join" enabled.
Then install the profile to the device. It should now connect automatically to an access point with the given credentials.
https://help.apple.com/configurator/mac/2.3/#/cadbf9e6ff